# Load an HTML template and to email

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails, email-template

I'd like to send a formatted HTML email from a custom component. I thought I would be able to create a `tmpl` file somewhere like `components/mycomponent/views/emailer/tmpl/default_email.php` and then in the view (at `components/mycomponent/views/emailer/view.email.php`) I'd be able to render the `default_email` view with the data pulled from the model and then send it.

It appears the "normal" Joomla way is to do a `sprintf` with a language string to generate the email.

Is there no way to render the template file in the view prior to sending the email?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways to render internally a page from a view.

Basically, you call the view and capture the output in a variable.

For instance, in FoF you can do it in this way:

```
    ob_start();
    F0FDispatcher::getTmpInstance(
            'com_mycomponent',
            'theview',
            $config
        )->dispatch();
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

You can also call the Url with a cURL connection, but it is slower since you must open a new network connection to render the page.

Comment: @Anibal-- will this render the complete template including menu items etc? Or will it just render the single template item?

Comment: Hi, this sample code renders only a component view. If you go for the alternative calling a page via an Url, you'll get the whole page.

Comment: @anibal- how do you specify the specific `tmpl` file to render? Could you please provide more detail on the specific usage in your answer?

Comment: Joomla and Fof render tmpl/default.php. If you have other layouts, then you can specify parameters in $config.